# Lotus Notes - undo "keep me informed of updates" after declining a meeting

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes

A while ago I declined a meeting and asked to be informed of updates on this meeting.

In the mean time I do not want to be informed anymore but can't seem to undo this.

I am not in the invitee list anymore and can't see how to avoid receiving updates every single time.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd need to re-accept one of the updates and then re-decline it and choose not to receive updates again. When you decline, it sends a notice to the chair, including the instructions on whether or not to keep you updated. You can find the decline instances in your "entries and notices" view in the calendar or in your All Documents view in your mail if it's set to display calendar entries.

Here is a link explaining how calendaring and scheduling work. 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/cs-pt1/